# MySQL query on a generated result set

Tags: mysql

I am not sure what term I need to be searching for, but I could not find anything.

I am creating a MySQL query, ordering by high score and adding a row count column to return the position of the user, now each user has a column saying if they want to receive an email or not which would be emails = 1, but I need to first get my row count column as this is not stored. Obviously I could do this with server side scripting but it would be great to do a query on the result set generated.

```
set @N = 0; # MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
SELECT email, @N := @N + 1 AS position, overallScore FROM `quizUsers`
ORDER BY overallScore DESC
LIMIT 0, 3000
```

So that is my base query, is there now a way to say

```
WHERE emails = 1
```

Comment: Re your title, what about a MySQL query on a generated result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the calculated value on an aliases result of the order by and have your WHERE clause on the inner query.
Try this:

```
set @N = 0;
-- Note calculation is made in the outer query, ie *after* ordering 
SELECT email, overallScore, @N := @N + 1 AS position 
FROM (
    SELECT email, overallScore, emails
    FROM quizUsers
    ORDER BY overallScore DESC) x -- Note ORDER BY is on the inner query
WHERE emails = 1
LIMIT 0, 3000
```

Comment: if the first 10 people don't want an email, then your query will indicate the 11th ranked person is 1st.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
That returned the users with emails = 1, but the order was just the order of the people who emails = 1 not the overall order

Comment: Ok I had to do the count within the FROM statement, but got it working now.

set @N = 0;
SELECT email, overallScore, title, forename, surname, position 
FROM 
(SELECT id, email, overallScore, title, forename, surname, @N := @N + 1       AS position, emails 
FROM quizUsers 
ORDER BY overallScore DESC) 
AS rankings 
WHERE emails=1 
ORDER BY id

Comment: Oh - I didn't know you wanted the where *after* the ordering (I thought you wanted the ranking of those who have emails). I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I have used Mysql for around 5 years and never known about this fuctionality, I have always used joins, I think this opens up different possibilities, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can SELECT on a SELECT, sometimes called a subquery. MySql will call it a "derived table" in an explain of the query. Just wrap the SELECT in parenthesis and name it. Then you can treat the SELECT like it is a real table.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT email, @N := @N + 1 AS position ...) AS rankings WHERE emails=1
```

You will end up with less than 3000 records, but the positions will be all correct.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
SELECT email, @N := @N + 1 AS position, overallScore FROM `quizUsers` WHERE emails = 1

ORDER BY overallScore DESC

LIMIT 0, 3000
```

I think you want the rowcount of all users and then extract the ones with email=1 right? 
Then you would need a sub query I think, something like:

```
Select * FROM (SELECT email, @N := @N + 1 AS position, overallScore FROM `quizUsers` WHERE emails = 1

ORDER BY overallScore DESC) as T1 Where T1.emails = 1

LIMIT 0, 3000
```